Merge image and SwiftUI view then save to gallery
When I press the save button on the on the photo I took with the custom camera I created, I want to add the DecibelLabel view to top of the photo and save it to the gallery, but no matter what I try, it doesn't quite work. Can you help me about this?
Here is some funcs for saving and taking photo, camera preview and DecibelLabel

    func takePic() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isTaken.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
          self.session.stopRunning()
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        
        print("pic taken..")
        
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
            print("Fotoğraf verisi alınamadı.")
            return
        }
        
        self.picData    = imageData
    }
    
    
    func savePic() {
        guard let image = UIImage(data: self.picData) else {
            print("Fotoğraf kaydedilemedi")
            self.isSaved = false
            return
        }
        
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        
        self.isSaved = true
        print("saved successfully..")
    }
}


struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var camera: CameraModel
    var size: CGSize

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        
        camera.preview =  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.frame.size = size
        
        camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        
        camera.session.startRunning()
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}


struct DecibelLabel: View {
    var decibel: Int
    @State private var maxDecibel = 0
    @State private var minDecibel = 0
    @State private var firstTime = true
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(String(decibel))
                .font(.system(size: 75))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding(.leading, 25)
            Text("dB")
                .font(.system(size: 35))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Group {
                    Text("MIN: \(minDecibel)")
                    Text("MAX: \(maxDecibel)")
                }
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .background(.black.opacity(0.6))
        .onChange(of: decibel) {
            if decibel > maxDecibel {
                maxDecibel = decibel
                
                if firstTime {
                    minDecibel = decibel
                    firstTime = false
                }
            }
            if decibel < minDecibel {
                minDecibel = decibel
            }
        }
        
    }
}

